# Setting onClickListeners to edit text box in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I have a coFragment.xml file that includes an EditText box, and some buttons. In my coFragment.java file, I would like to register onClickListeners to the buttons, so that when they're pressed, text will be added to the EditText box.

My coFragment.java file currently has

```
public class CoFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parentViewGroup,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.coFragment, parentViewGroup, false);

    EditText input = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.input_id);

    Button oneButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.one_button_id);
    Button twoButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.two_button_id);
    Button threeButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.three_button_id);

    oneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    twoButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    threeButton.setOnClickListener(this)
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.one_button_id:
            input.append("1");
            break;
        case R.id.two_button_id:
            input.append("2");
            break;
        case R.id.three_button_id:
            input.append("3");
            break;
}
```

Obviously, I currently cannot access the `input` EditText object in the `onClick` method. How might I go about getting the functionality that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access `EditText` outside `onCreateView()` you need to declare it outside any method and initialize it in `onCreateView()`-

```
 private EditText input;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parentViewGroup,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

....

 input = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_id);
....
}
```

Now you can use `input` anywhere inn your fragment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response - when I try what you suggested I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Did you copied exactly what I wrote ? Its v.findViewById() and not getView().findViewById

Comment: aah, ok, I used getView, not v. Everything's working now, thanks for your help, much appreciated!